# Can web apps in iPhone call inapp for virtual things purchase?

Tags: iphone

If I would like to write a web apps that users can purchase some virtual things, can I call the iphone inapp? or I can use other payment methods?

Comment: You ought to check this doesn't go against Apple's terms and agreements. I seem to remember seeing somewhere that physical app purchases were ok on your app but not virtual purchases, but maybe my memory is not correct. But you should check, Apple are touchy about this sort of thing and will reject your app if you do something they don't like.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant, you will need to implement special non standard tags into your application, when the user clicks on these links they will have some thing like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        NSString *urlAbsolute = [request.URL absoluteString];
        if ([urlAbsolute hasPrefix:@"YourSpecialTag://"])
        {
            //YourSpecialTag://BuyID=100
            //Parse the url
            //Get the id = 100
            //Continue with in-app purchase
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: oh you mean, you will not implement it in iPhone? your application will be just web?

Comment: i will implement it in iPhone. But I will in form of web apps. So, I afraid I cannot call inapps to have payment